# Construct a matrix given the null space of A

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Construct a matrix A with the null space spanned by the vectors $(2, -3, 1, 1, -1)^t, (1,0,-2,1,1)^t, (2,-2,1,0,-1)^t$ and $(-8,3,1,1,1)$ in $R^5$.

I have come to the conclusion that the four vectors are linearly dependent while three of them are linearly independent, including the vectors $v_1, v_2$ and $v_3$. But how should I proceed from this? I have only done tasks where you can calculate A with the help of the cross product between two vectors, but it does not work in this case.

My textbook does not provide a complete solution, only the answer unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would form a matrix $\vec{X}$ from these four vectors so that the row space of this matrix will be a null space of your target matrix.

Now solve $\vec{X}\vec{n}=\vec{0}$ and the space of the solutions will be the null space  of the matrix $\vec{X}$, in other words, it will be formed with the vectors that form the matrix with the null space equal to the row space of $\vec{X}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, sounds so obvious now as you write this, then I finally understand how to do!